# Geocoder APIs returning range of addresses

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, android-maps-v2, android-location

I am attempting to use latitude and longitude coordinates to resolve a specific address. Currently, the Geocoder APIs will occasionally return a range of addresses, even if the selected location is an individual house rather than something like an apartment building.

The below method accepts a latitude, longitude, and Activity and returns the `Address` object returned from the Geocoder API:

```
public static Address resolveAddress(double latitude, double longitude, Activity activity) {
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(activity);
    List<Address> addresses;
    try {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0 ) {
            Log.d(TAG, "resolveAddress: " + addresses.get(0).toString());
            return addresses.get(0);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

The `getFromLocation()` method provided by the Geocoder API accepts a `maxResults` parameter as it's last argument, which you can see in the above code is set to 1. Even so, while only a single result is returned, a range of street numbers is returned in the single result.

I would assume that GPS and the Android Location service is accurate enough to resolve to a single house. How can I use latitude and longitude coordinates to best determine a single address?

Comment: Can you please give a sample latitude,longitude pair that has multiple street numbers in the result?

Comment: Sure, using an emulator with longitude set at `-122.101` and latitude at `37.412`, I get a result of `483-487 Victory Avenue, Mountain View, California`.

Comment: I believe the lat,lng you are using isn't precise enough.  I was able to get the same results as you with those coordinates. When I did a geocode request for the address "487 Victory Avenue, Mountain View, California" I got a lat,lng of "37.4118933,-122.1008218." If I put this lat,lng in a reverse geocoding request the first results in the results array is no longer a range of addresses and is just "487 Victory Avenue, Mountain View, California" If you use a more precise lat,lng do you get better results?

Comment: Using a longitude of `-122.1008218` and latitude of `37.4118933` provides the same range of addresses.